# error in inserting data into multiple tables with relation delete cascade

Tags: c#, mysql

As I try to input values and click submit button it says an error in exception

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near"paul@yahoo.com')' (the email that i input) at line 1

```
int MobileNo;
string Mobile = txtMobile.Text;
int.TryParse(Mobile, out MobileNo);
MySqlConnection connection = new MySqlConnection(MyConnectionString);
MySqlCommand cmd;
connection.Open();
try 
{
    cmd = connection.CreateCommand();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO phonebook(Id,Name,MobileNo)VALUES(@Id,@Name,@MobileNo)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Name", txtName.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@MobileNo", Mobile);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( ,@email)";
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Id", int.Parse(txtId.Text));
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtEmail1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
}
finally
{
    if (connection.State == ConnectionState.Open)
    {
        connection.Close();
        LoadData();
    }
}
```

[image: the image is my table]

Comment: You are not including the Id in the second query.. Please include it and then check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change

> "INSERT INTO email(Id,email)VALUES( ,@email)";

To

> "INSERT INTO email (Id,email) VALUES (@Id ,@email)";

You're specifying that you're inserting data into two columns, but only supplying a single value.